# Firebase and VueJS: How to handle users that login with Google and don't register in my app? User profile management

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I have an app with a LOGIN page and a REGISTER page. Both pages have a "Sign in with Google" button, as well as a regular login and password input form for those that don't want to sign in with Google. I am also using FireStore to create user profile documents for registered users. When the user also logs in, the app will query the user's profile for use throughout the app. This all works fine.

I noticed that a google user does not need to "register"...he can still click the login button and it will "sign him up" automatically because that's how Google Auth Provider works. However, since he did not "register", he does not yet have a profile. In this case, I had to write some logic so a profile would be created for a Google user. Although this logic works, I just wonder if this is the best way to do this. Are there best practices for handling Google/Social logins for people skipping the traditional "registering" pages? I know most people would probably head to the register page and register, but there will undoubtedly be some people that will skip that and go start to the LOGIN page and sign in via Google that way.

Here's how I'm handling the login page with Google login button:

> `login.vue`

```
async logInWithGoogle() {
      try {
        const provider = new this.$fireAuthObj.GoogleAuthProvider()
        const userCredentials = await this.$fireAuth.signInWithRedirect(
          provider
        ) ....
```

Then in my Store (in my case, Vuex state management pattern), I have the following actions:

> `store.js`

First, this onAuthStateChanged observer will notice the new user state and do the following code:

```
  async onAuthStateChangedAction({ commit, dispatch }, { authUser }) {
    if (authUser) {
      console.log('user committing from onAuthStateChangedAction...')
      commit('SET_CURRENT_USER', authUser)

      console.log(
        'fetchUserProfile action dispatching from onAuthStateChangedAction...'
      )
      await dispatch('fetchUserProfile', authUser)
    } else {
      dispatch('logOutUser')
    }
  }
```

That onAuthStateChanged observer will fetch the user's profile (and this is the logic I am concerned with...not sure if this is an ideal way to handle user's logging in via Google for first time and bypassing registration:

```
 async fetchUserProfile({ commit }, user) {
    try {
      const docRef = this.$fireStore.collection('users').doc(user.uid)

      const profile = await docRef.get()
      if (profile.exists) {
        commit('SET_USER_PROFILE', await profile.data())
        console.log(
          'user profile EXISTS and set from fetchUserProfile action'
        )
      } else {
        console.log('profile does not exist! Creating...')
        await docRef.set({
          displayName: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          uid: user.uid,
          photoUrl: user.photoURL,
          providerId: user.providerData[0].providerId,
          createdAt: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })
        const p = await docRef.get()
        commit('SET_USER_PROFILE', await p.data())
        console.log('user profile set')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('can not fetch profile', error)
    }
  },
```

Thanks for any tips or assurances that I am on the right (or wrong) path on handling this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an empty document with the user's uid and prompt them to "complete their profile"? Until they do so, force redirect them back to the profile page indefinitely.

Comment: Personally I think that is not a good UX . I want to make it as easy for them to use the app and I hope they stay. They can always edit their profile when ready. Thx for your suggestion!